# How to add smooth scrolling to navbar in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a react project and I can't seem to get smooth scrolling to work, even after installing the 'react-scroll' package and creating a navbar hook.

Here's my code:
`

```
import React from 'react'
import Icon from './svg'

export default function Banner() {

    return (
        <React.Fragment> 
            <header className="header-section two">
    <div className="header">
        <div className="header-bottom-area">
            <div className="container custom-container">
                <div className="header-menu-content">
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-xl p-0">
                        <a className="site-logo site-title" href="/"><img src="./assets/images/logo.png" width="63%" alt="giga-logo"/></a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler d-block d-xl-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="toggle-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav main-menu" id="nav-list">
                                    <li><a href='about' >About us</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/plan">Plans</a></li>
                                <li className="menu_has_children">
                                    <a href="#0">Business<i className="las la-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul className="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="service.html">Leased Lines</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="service-details.html">Corporate Solutions</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href>Resellers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
                                <p className="btn--base"><a href="my-login-portal">Login</a></p> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </nav>
                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                </header>
```

`

I've tried traditionally linking with  tags as well as other  and onClick methods with no success. Any help would be appreciated as this is my first (serious) React project after graduation and I would like to finish this website for my client on time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you scrolling to elements using #`id`?

If so then you could enable smooth scrolling via CSS and that should take care of it:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

> The scroll-behavior CSS property sets the behavior for a scrolling box
> when scrolling is triggered by the navigation or CSSOM scrolling APIs.

[MSDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)